# How can i get sum of queryset lists and make jsonresponse?

Tags: python, json, django

**views.py**

```
from itertools import chain

def post_list(request):

        i=1
        while i:
            list_i = Post.objects.filter(title__startswith="i")
            post_list = list(chain('' + ',' + 'list_i'))
            if len(post_list) >= 5 :
                break

    return JsonResponse(serializers.serialize('json', post_list), safe=False)
```

I want make post_list that is sum of list_1, list_2, ..,list_i and make it serialized.

But it gives me AttributeError as follows.

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Django Version: 1.9.7
Python Version: 3.5.2
Installed Applications:
[...I omitted]
Installed Middleware:
[...I omitted]

Traceback:

File "/home/keepair/djangogirls/myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/keepair/djangogirls/myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/keepair/djangogirls/blog/views.py" in post_list
  33.     return JsonResponse(serializers.serialize('json', post_list), safe=False)

File "/home/keepair/djangogirls/myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/serializers/__init__.py" in serialize
  129.     s.serialize(queryset, **options)

File "/home/keepair/djangogirls/myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/serializers/base.py" in serialize
  83.             concrete_model = obj._meta.concrete_model

Exception Type: AttributeError at /
Exception Value: 'str' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

How can i solve this?

Thanks for reading my question.

Comment: I don't understand your code. What does `list(chain('' + ',' + 'list_i'))` do? If you have a queryset `list_i`, why are you making it a string in `list(chain('' + ',' + 'list_i'))`?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by `getting sum of queryset`? Sum of what?

Comment: I want list_1 + list_2 + list_3 ... until Post's sum number is gte=5. Because I'm new in programming, i struggle to follow rule of python itertools, chain. `list(chain('' + ',' + 'list_i'))` is my effort to use chain function. Is there any other good way?

Comment: Oh, *that's* what you're trying to do. No, itertools chain is entirely inappropriate here.

Comment: I want Sum of list_i . If there are 5 posts in list_1, only need list_1, but if 0 posts in list_1 and 2 posts in list_2 and 4 posts in list_3,  i want Sum of list_1 and list_2 and list_3 .

Comment: So.. what should i do? please help me Im very disappointed now.

Comment: It seems like English isn't your first language. `sum` means the total, e.g. `sum([1,2,3])` is 6. `len`gth, on the other hand, is the size of a container, so `len([1,2,3])` is 3. You have several other fundamental misunderstandings that I've tried to address in my answer. I hope it helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you have a serious disconnect between string values and text values.

```
In [126]: x = 3

In [127]: print("x")
x

In [128]: print(x)
3

In [129]: print(str(x))
3
```

Based on your code, I'm *pretty sure* you thought that `print("x")` would print out `3`. That's never going to be true the way it's written. I say that because you have

```
i=1
while i:
    list_i = Post.objects.filter(title__startswith="i")
```

Aside from just being wrong in general, looking at your other code, I'm *pretty sure* that you expect this to return `Post`s that begin with `1`. It won't, it will only return posts that begin with `'i'`.

Here, you're also creating a variable `i`, and you're using `while i`, but you never change `i` anywhere. If what you're looking for is to make sure that your post list has at least 5 items in it, then you're going about this all wrong.

First, what you need is a post list:

```
post_list = []
```

If you want to filter by numbers where the post titles start with `1` then `2`, and so on, you're going to need a counter, too:

```
count = 0
```

Now, you need to loop while the list has less than 5 elements:

```
while len(post_list) < 5:
```

Then you need to append stuff to the list. What stuff? The posts you get. But we're also going to want to bump up that count each time through so we're not adding the same posts:

```
    count += 1
    post_list.extend(Post.objects.filter(title__startswith=str(count)))
```

Putting that all together, you get:

def post_list(request):

```
post_list = []
count = 0
while len(post_list) < 5:
    count += 1
    post_list.extend(Post.objects.filter(title__startswith=str(count)))

return JsonResponse(serializers.serialize('json', post_list), safe=False)
```

However, there's one thing we haven't considered yet - what if you *never* get more than 5 posts? What if your system only has 4? This is going to (never) end badly - you're going to enter an infinite loop. So we should add another sentinel - we know from counting in grade school:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,
10,
11,
12,
...
19,
20,
21,
...
```

Every number above 9 is going to begin with a number 1-9. So we can definitely state that if our count goes to 10+ that one of our filters would have already picked it up. Even 222,392,138,902 x 10^20 starts with 2. So we should amend our `while` condition to this:

```
while count < 10 and len(post_list) < 5:
```

And we'll have a solution that I *think* does what you want, unless you had some different ideas about filtering.

Comment: It is good lecture for me. As you think, english is not my first language, so i have trouble with reading and understanding what has been written in english. But your explanation is very good for me. Thank you. It was very helpful for me.

Comment: If my answer is the best solution to your problem you should mark it accepted by clicking the check mark to the left <---

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be using `chain`. `chain` method would chain lists together, but you don't want all of them together, so you should just use plain list methods:

```
def post_list(request):
    result = []
    i = 1
    while True:
        list_i = Post.objects.filter(title__startswith=str(i))
        result.extend(list_i)
        if len(result) >= 5:
            result = result[:5]
            break
        i += 1
    return JsonResponse(serializers.serialize('json', result), safe=False)
```

No offence but reading your code I feel like you are lack of some fundamental knowledge of python/programming. I would suggest you learning some basics about python before jumping into django development, it would save you a lot of time figuring out stuff like this.